# Is there anything to prove in this corollary?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if  $B$ is not finite and $B\subset A$, then A is not finite.

I mean the statement is very trivial, but I'm having an issue actually writing what I would deem a good proof of this. The only idea I have is of letting $x\in B$ and  then show it is in $A$, but even that is trivial because I'm given that in my assumption.

Comment: You have to be careful.  It seems trivial, but requires a rigorous proof.   Go to the definition of "finite" set:   E.g.   " A set $S$ is finite iff there is a bijection $f:S \to \mathbb{N}_k,$ for some $k\geq 1$ or $S$ is empty."

Comment: Indeed, it all depends on your definition of “finite”, which is why the answers so far may very well be useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there's an injective map $A\stackrel{\phi}{\hookrightarrow} n\in\mathbb{N}$

Since $B$ is infinite, there's an injective map $n\stackrel{\theta}{\hookrightarrow} B$ (I think this is the only point where one has to be careful not to use the axiom of choice)

But the inclusion $B\subseteq A$ gives us an injective map $B\stackrel{id_B}{\hookrightarrow}A$

But then we have a chain of injective maps

$$n\stackrel{\theta}{\hookrightarrow}B\stackrel{id_B}{\hookrightarrow}A\stackrel{\phi}{\hookrightarrow}n$$

But then, by Cantor-Bernstein's theorem, there exists a bijection $B\stackrel{\gamma}{\longleftrightarrow}n$. Absurd.

Comment: Your explanation seems to make the most sense to me, I haven't covered the axiom of choice yet, but beyond that it still makes sense. I never thought of $B\subset A$ as having an injective map, but thinking about it, it does.

Comment: By the way, Carsten Schultz is right. If your definition of "finite set" comes from $$B\text{ is infinite }\Leftrightarrow \exists C\subsetneq B,\,\exists f:B\hookrightarrow C$$
this proof doesn't work (in the sense that it depends on the axiom of choice).

Comment: The definition I used is: $$B \text{ is finite }\Leftrightarrow\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\,\exists f:B\hookrightarrow n$$

Comment: Your definition is the one that I am familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

As $B$ is not finite, there is an injective function $f:\mathbb{N}\to B$ (by definition).  Define $g:\mathbb{N}\to A:x\mapsto f(x)$.  Now $$g(x)=g(y)\iff f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$$ by injectivity of $f$.  Hence $g$ is an injection to $A$.  Hence $A$ is not finite by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the *inclusion* map, $\iota: B \to A, \iota(b) \mapsto b$. This is definitely an injection. Therefore $\operatorname{card} B \leq \operatorname{card} A$.